# Converting Laravel Blades to Vue 3 (what's Vue Conditional Rendering equivalent of Laravel Blade Directives?)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vuejs3

I decided to change the question and tried it alone. I've tried to convert Laravel Blade to Vue 3 page, but the result doesn't as I expected.

Here's the Laravel Blade code:

```html
<table id="mahasiswa" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="20vh">No</th>
                            <th width="75vh">NIM</th>
                            <th>Nama</th>
                            @foreach($kriteria as $krit)
                            <th>{{$krit->nama}}</th>
                            @endforeach
                            <th width="100vh">Aksi</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php $no = 1; ?>
                        @if(!empty($mahasiswa))
                        {{-- variable $mahasiswa berisi nilai dari setiap kriteria per mahasiswa --}}
                        @foreach($mahasiswa as $mhs)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                            <td>{{$mhs->nim}}</td>
                            <td>{{$mhs->nama}}</td>
                            @if(count($mhs->nilai) == 0)
                            @foreach($kriteria as $krit)
                            <td><i>Tidak ada data</i></td>
                            @endforeach
                            @endif
                            @foreach($mhs->nilai as $nilai)
                            <td>{{$nilai->nilai_alt}}</td>
                            @endforeach
                            <td class="text-center">
                                @if(count($mhs->nilai) == 0)
                                <a href="{{ route('nilai.tambah',['id' => $mhs->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                                    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                                @else
                                <a href="{{ route('nilai.edit', ['id' => $mhs->id]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">
                                    <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                </a>
                                @endif
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And here's my conversion effort to Vue 3 (I use Tailwind CSS 3 in case you got confused):

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import { onMounted, ref, computed } from 'vue'
import SideBar from './../../../components/SideBar.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        SideBar,
    },

    setup() {
        let peserta1 = ref([])
        let result = ref([])
        let penilaian1 = ref([])
        let subkriteria = ref([])

        onMounted(() => {
            axios
                .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/penilaian1')
                .then((result) => {
                    penilaian1.value = result.data
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response)
                })
        })

        onMounted(() => {
            axios
                .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/penilaian1/table_sk1')
                .then((result) => {
                    subkriteria.value = result.data
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response)
                })
        })
        onMounted(() => {
            axios
                .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/penilaian1/peserta1')
                .then((result) => {
                    peserta1.value = result.data
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err.response)
                })
        })
        const transpose = () => {
            penilaian1.value.forEach((dat) => {
                if (!result.value.find((r) => r.nim === dat.nim)) {
                    result.value.push({ nim: dat.nim, nama: dat.nama })
                }
            })
            penilaian1.value.forEach((dat) => {
                let res = result.value.find((r) => r.nim === dat.nim)
                res[dat.id_sk1] = dat.nilai
            })
            console.log(result)
        }

        return {
            peserta1,
            penilaian1,
            subkriteria,
            transpose,
        }
    },
}
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="relative min-h-screen md:flex">
        <SideBar />
        <div class="flex-1">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 class="px-6 py-6 mb-6 text-3xl font-extrabold">
                    Data Penilaian
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="flex-1">
                    <div class="overflow-y-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
                        <div class="py-2 inline-clip sm:px-6 lg:px-12">
                            <div
                                class="overflow-hidden shadow-md sm:rounded-lg"
                            >
                                <table class="min-w-full">
                                    <thead class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-700">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th
                                                scope="col"
                                                class="px-6 py-3 text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-gray-700 uppercase  dark:text-gray-400"
                                            >
                                                NIM
                                            </th>
                                            <th
                                                scope="col"
                                                class="px-6 py-3 text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-gray-700 uppercase  dark:text-gray-400"
                                            >
                                                Nama
                                            </th>
                                            <th
                                                v-for="subkriteria in subkriteria"
                                                :key="subkriteria.id"
                                                scope="col"
                                                class="px-6 py-3 text-xs font-medium tracking-wider text-left text-gray-700 uppercase  dark:text-gray-400"
                                            >
                                                {{ subkriteria.nama }}
                                            </th>
                                            <th
                                                scope="col"
                                                class="relative px-6 py-3"
                                            >
                                                <span class="sr-only"
                                                    >Aksi</span
                                                >
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <!-- Product 1 -->
                                        <template v-if="peserta1.count == 0">
                                            <tr
                                                v-for="peserta1 in transpose"
                                                :key="peserta1.id"
                                                class="bg-white border-b  dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-600"
                                            >
                                                <td
                                                    class="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900  whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white"
                                                >
                                                    {{ peserta1.nim }}
                                                </td>
                                                <td
                                                    class="px-6 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500  whitespace-nowrap dark:text-gray-400"
                                                >
                                                    {{ peserta1.nama }}
                                                </td>
                                                <template
                                                    v-if="peserta1.length == 0"
                                                >
                                                    <td
                                                        v-for="subkriteria in subkriteria"
                                                        :key="subkriteria.id"
                                                        class="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-right  whitespace-nowrap"
                                                    >
                                                        Tidak ada data
                                                    </td>
                                                </template>
                                                <template>
                                                    <td
                                                        v-for="penilaian in penilaian1"
                                                        :key="penilaian.id"
                                                        class="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-right  whitespace-nowrap"
                                                    >
                                                        {{ penilaian.nilai }}
                                                    </td>
                                                </template>
                                                <td
                                                    v-if="penilaian.nilai == 0"
                                                    class="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-right  whitespace-nowrap"
                                                >
                                                    <router-link
                                                        :to="{
                                                            name: 'penilaian1.tambah',
                                                            params: {
                                                                id: penilaian.nim,
                                                            },
                                                        }"
                                                        class="text-blue-600  hover:text-blue-900 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:underline"
                                                        >Tambah</router-link
                                                    >
                                                </td>
                                                <td
                                                    v-else
                                                    class="px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-right  whitespace-nowrap"
                                                >
                                                    <router-link
                                                        :to="{
                                                            name: 'penilaian1.edit',
                                                            params: {
                                                                id: penilaian.nim,
                                                            },
                                                        }"
                                                        class="text-blue-600  hover:text-blue-900 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:underline"
                                                        >Edit</router-link
                                                    >
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </template>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But the result is:

[Result in VueJS 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VtgD.png)

I don't see any columns loop based on criteria data table (so criteria columns can show dynamically based on this table) and nilai/grade data with empty grade data

What I expect is:

[Original app in Laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg9n1.png)

Please guide me for Vue conversion of Laravel Blade, also tell me the Vue Conditional Rendering equivalent of Laravel Blade Directives (the main topic and problem) because PHP and JavaScript are different and please give me some feedback about my Vue code.

Answer (score 0):

Check `console` first if something goes wrong in front-end apps, reconsider edit your question add Message in your `console`, and simple `codepen` if you want your audience know more about your problem.

And for your code, it mostly will not work,

```
// Dont do this
<th v-for="subkriteria in subkriteria" ...>
    {{ subkriteria.nama }}
</th>

// Try this
<th v-for="sub in subkriteria" ...>
    {{ sub.nama }}
</th>
```

see the docs, [Vue JS List Rendering](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html)

And If i remember correctly, in below code

```
// Will not work
<tr v-for="peserta1 in transpose" ...>
    ...
</tr>

const transpose = () => {
     penilaian1.value.forEach((dat) => {
          if (!result.value.find((r) => r.nim === dat.nim)) {
               result.value.push({
                    nim: dat.nim,
                    nama: dat.nama
               });
          }
     });
     penilaian1.value.forEach((dat) => {
          let res = result.value.find((r) => r.nim === dat.nim);
          res[dat.id_sk1] = dat.nilai;
     });
     console.log(result);
};
```

`transpose` is `method`, it need `object`or `array` or `range` in `v-for`.